# Problem with table of contents and chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I am writing my Master's Thesis and am in a bit of a pickle with the table of contents.

I want to add a preface and abstract as chapters, *preceding* the table of contents, have them show up

- I want to add a preface and abstract as chapters.
- They have to precede the table of contents.
- However, the words 'Chapter 1:' preceding 'Preface' should not be added, and
- 'Preface' and 'Abstract' have to show up in the table of contents.

My Table of contents should look something like this:

Preface --- i

Abstract --- ii

1 Thesis subject --- 1

2 Amazing and award-deserving results --- 2.

Any help would be appreciated. I know how to swap the numbering (roman-arabic) myself. I tried using \chapter*{Preface} but then Preface disappears from the ToC.

Comment: @Marijn The link you provided answered my question. Could you tell me what I am supposed to do with my question now by site policy (flag it as duplicate, delete it, ...)?

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof I will vote to close as a duplicate.